# Performance issue: use "link_to" or "a"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For links that don't require much controller or options, is it better to use `a` html tag? Will there be any performance impact on using `link_to` rails tag unnecessarily?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Everywhere you can write static content instead of dynamic content, you'll see better performance. If using `link_to` makes things a lot easier to write and understand in a particular case, then use it, but if you yourself think it's unnecessary, save the CPU time and write the a tag yourself.

This is discussed specifically as it pertains to Rails helpers [in this article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Rails-Performance). According to the article:

> A number of helpers in Rails core will run rather slowly. In general, all helpers that take a URL hash will invoke the routing module to generate the shortest URL referencing the underlying controller action. This implies that several routes in the route file need to be examined, which is a costly process, most of the time... For pages displaying a large number of links, I have measured speed improvements up to 200% (given everything else has been optimized).

Comment: Does this answer still stand for Rails 3 after so many years?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use simple html tag instead link_to if you are using links for a simple get request(not ajax or other methods like post,put etc) with less controllers or less routing defined in app